# Initializing Deck of Cards C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a program in C++ but struggling a bit. Right now I have:

All needed #includes

```
enum Suit {SPADES=0, HEARTS=1, DIAMONDS=2, CLUBS=3}
typedef struct Card {
  Suit suit;
  int value;
} Card;

int main() {

Card deck[52];

int cardNum = 52;
int suitNum = 4;
int faceNum = 13;

for (int i = 0; i < suitNum; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < faceNum; j++) {
    deck[cardNum].suit = suitNum[i];
    deck[cardNum].value = faceNum[j];
    cardNum--;
  }
}
```

Obviously, this is incorrect. I am struggling to come up with the correct initialization here, and I have been working on this for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your post with the definition of `Suit`.

Comment: BTW, in C++, the `typedef` before `struct` is not necessary.

Comment: If your `cardNum, suitNum,` and `faceNum` are not changed, declare them as "static const".  This will allow the compiler to treat them as constants instead of variables.

Comment: The variable `suitNum` is a *single* integer.  What do you expect `suitNum[i]` to return?  Your compiler should emit some kind of warning or error here.  Similarly for `faceNum`.

Comment: Your coding style could use improvement.  1) Structures and variable names should differ by more than case, e.g. "Suit" and "suit".  2) Single integer variables can't be arrays; decide, e.g. `faceNum` and `faceNum[i]`.  3) The `main` function returns an `int`, so add a `return` statement (usually `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: To address a few of these, the struct was given to me to work with. The suitNum[i] was a sort of guess to be completely honest as well as the faceNum[j]. I had a strong feelings those were wrong, but I am drawing a complete blank

Comment: This is just a very small portion of the program. I am just struggling with the deck array initialization. The rest of the program involves randomizing and getting and printing a hand, which I am mostly ok with

Comment: The Suit definition is enum Suit {SPADES=0, HEARTS=1, DIAMONDS=2, CLUBS=3}

Comment: Nice comment about Suit definition.  Please **edit your post** with the definition.  Put it in the code section.

Comment: *"Obviously, this is incorrect"* -- what is obvious to one person is not necessarily obvious to others. And sometimes "obvious" does not hold up under careful scrutiny. So I would ask you to indulge a bit and write out why you believe your code is incorrect, and write our precisely what you want your code to do. *See also [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)*.

Comment: I do apologize if my comments are unclear. I'm very new to coding, and a lot of this is still going over my head. I guess I frequently feel like some things I should understand, I still don't. I lack a lot of confidence with programming to be completely honest. I appreciate all of the advice you guys are giving me here. Please, if you have any suggestions for a crash course in either C or C++ sort of basics, I would greatly appreciate that as well

Comment: @fatelarso I can suggest to not mix C and C++. Go for C++ and in the C++ way :)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to loop through the deck and assign new card values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardNum; ++i)
    deck[i] = Card(i / faceNum, i % faceNum);
```

Since `i` and `faceNum` are both integers, `i / faceNum` and `i % faceNum` are also integers. `i / faceNum` will range from 0 to 3, and `i % faceNum` will range from 0 to 12 as the code runs through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this

```cpp
enum Suit { SPADES = 0, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, MAX_SUIT };

struct Card {
  Suit suit;
  int value;
};

int main()
{
    const int faceNum = 13;
    Card deck[faceNum * Suit::MAX_SUIT];

    Card* next = deck;
    for (int i = 0; i < Suit::MAX_SUIT; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < faceNum; j++) {
        *next++ = { static_cast<Suit>(i) , j };
      }
    }
}
```

Good points:

- less constants, all you have to setup is the Suits and the number of faces, no other magic numbers around.
- you do not have to deal with strange formulas for the index in the deck (no worries about empty spaces or not init cards, overwrites or array overflow in case of wrong indexing)

I cannot say that it's the "best" solution as some choices are really up to you and your working group.

My 2 cents,
Welcome on stack overflow!
Stefano